# Check radio button programmatically is not working in every browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check a radio button based on the path in the URL.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function make_url() {
        var results_url = window.location.pathname.split("/");

        console.log(results_url); // ["", "tradeshows"]

        if (results_url[1] == "tradeshows") {
            $("#radio2").attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else if (results_url[2] == "tradeshows") {
            $("#radio2").attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    }
});

<ul class="cd-filter-content cd-filters list" id="radioButtons" onChange="make_url();" style="display: block; padding:0px;">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" checked="" id="radio1" name="radioButton" value="" data-filter=".radio2" class="filter">
        <label for="radio1" class="radio-label">All Events</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioButton" data-filter=".radio3" class="filter" value="1">
        <label for="radio2" class="radio-label" id="trade">Trade Shows</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The code is working fine on my local file system, but not on the server.

When I try it from the console, everytrhing works fine:

```
$("#radio2").attr('checked','checked');
```

I also tried it with vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('radio2').checked = true;
console.log(document.getElementById('radio2').checked); // false
```

And I tried a different solution with jQuery:

```
$('#radio2').prop('checked', true); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null
```

Comment: what's the difference between you first `if` and second `if`?? and try to keep this code in `$(document).ready(function(){//here})`

Comment: Can you try `jQuery("#radio2").attr('checked','checked');`

Comment: this is only working when running script on console of browser

Comment: it not working on if else condition or document ready

Comment: Could you please the output of the code 'window.location.pathname.split("/")' into staging server.

Comment: this.checked it returns false.

Comment: Please use "prop" in-place of "attr" to set the attributes into element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting following error.

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null
```

Then jquery returning `$('#radio2')` as null, Try logging `$('#radio2')` and check in console whether it returns any value or not.

**The main cause of the error is, when the function executing, there is no element present with id radio2**, there might be error if you are executing that function before DOM loads.

As you mentioned it works fine on your local machine and its not working on server, the respond time of server is little slower than local machine, so that element is not getting loaded and before that script is loading.

Please provide full more description of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't really make sense. The function `make_url` changes the radio button based on the given pathname in the URL, but the function only gets fired if the `ul` was changed, which will never happen since this event is not implemented.

If you remove the unneccessary `make_url` function, the radio buttons will be set as soon as the document is loaded (ready):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var results_url = window.location.pathname.split("/");

    if (results_url[1] == "tradeshows" || results_url[2] == "tradeshows") {
        $("#radio2").prop('checked', true);
    }
});

<ul class="cd-filter-content cd-filters list" id="radioButtons" style="display: block; padding:0px;">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" checked="" id="radio1" name="radioButton" value="" data-filter=".radio2" class="filter">
        <label for="radio1" class="radio-label">All Events</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioButton" data-filter=".radio3" class="filter" value="1">
        <label for="radio2" class="radio-label" id="trade">Trade Shows</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I also simplified your if-statement, since you checked the radio button wether the second or the third component of the pathname is equals "tradeshows".

Comment: i need when user has not checked radio button ; though he passes in tradeshows in url /tradeshows  then radio button gets higlighted (or on)

Comment: It seems like you didn't explain it good enough. What should happen if "tradeshows" is in the URL and when should that happen? When should the radio button get checked if it's not checked by the user?

Comment: i just need to highlight the bubble when tardeshow is set in browser

Comment: Which means "when the page is loaded and if the URL includes "tradeshows" then check the radiobutton with id "radio2""?

Comment: yes exactly /tradeshows then the radio button get cheked through js

Comment: Based on the code you provided, this is exactly what I did. You see: if the document is loaded, this function gets fired after "ready". Then the pathname gets splitted and if the second (1) or the third (2) in this array is equals to "tradeshows", the radio button (`#radio2`) is checked.